# How to center variable number of columns in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css

Having this html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the grid has 12 columns, there will be a column of 3 that will be empty.
Thing is that the html above is just a mock. Javascript will receive a number of columns.
And for each column it will print a:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <h6>Text</h6>
</div>
```

Meaning that there can be max 4 columns for each row.
But if javascript gets 5 columns, it should print:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <h6>Text</h6>
    </div>
```

As the last column (col-md-12) is completly alone. Having it as "col-md-3" will push it at left.
I can solve it with javascript, with some function to calculate the columns for each row. But I wonder if this is doable through css and maybe flex directive.

Comment: So you're happy with a column missing in your first case? You question is a bit hard to reason about... If you want to always fill the available space - you don't even need JS

Comment: yes. if there are 5 cols, i need the first four to be col-3. whike the last has to be col-12

Comment: What have you tried - related to JavaScript? Mind sharing your best research and code?

Comment: Haven't tried js yet. But I wondered if there is some nice css trick to adjust the columnsd in some other way, when the number of cols for a row is variable.

Comment: js-solution should not be that complivated, but as I said, I wonder if it is doable with css only.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bootstrap 5

***Simply add `justify-content: center` to the row elment style or add class `justify-content-center`***

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <div class="col-3 p-4 bg-primary">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-3 p-4 bg-success">World</div>
    <div class="col-3 p-4 bg-danger">Foo</div>
    <div class="col-12 p-4 bg-warning">Bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```